# why unique validation for string field not working in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I do not want the user to enter a duplicate value in the database
I put a field made of string that I want to be unique, even though I put it in the output, but unfortunately it does not work, ie the condition of being unique is not checked
Thank you for your help

```
public function select_date_time(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'date' => 'required', 'unique:times',
        'hour' => 'required',
    ];
    $message = [
        'date.required' => 'please enter date',
        'hour.required' => 'please enter hours',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $message);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        // return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        return redirect(route('doctor.profile'))
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    $doctor_date = new Time();
    $doctor_date->date = $request->date;
    $doctor_date->hour = $request->hour;
    $doctor_date->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $doctor_date->save();
    return back()->with('success', true);
}
```

Comment: The `$request->date;` timestamp format needs to be match with your `times` table  `date` timestamp column

Comment: Another quick tip, use [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) instead of your implementation. It will automatically handle errors, redirect back with them and input too, so you can remove a lot of lines there.